# KnockoutJS - A computed writable observable doesn't update bindings correctly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have created a custom binding for validating  observable with a regex pattern but i have some problems on computed observable. I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/melck/88vnx9ka/7/

I want a message on my computed observable when he has a wrong entry like temp4.
How can i do it without trigger a message on temp2 ?

Can u help me to solve this problems ?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.validate = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
    var field = value.field || '';
    var message = value.message || '';
    var pattern = value.pattern || null;
    var placement = value.placement || 'bottom';
    // If field not valid
    if (!pattern.test(field())) {
        // We show error
        $(element).addClass('error-tooltip');
        $(element).tooltip({
            title: message,
            placement: placement,
            trigger: 'manual'
        });
        $(element).tooltip('show');
        // If we have a last valid value
        if (typeof element.lastValidValue != 'undefined') {
            // We replace
            field(element.lastValidValue);
            // Timeout to hide tootip
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(element).tooltip('destroy')
            }, 3000);
        }
    } else {
        // Otherwise we keep last valid value
        element.lastValidValue = field();
        $(element).removeClass('error-tooltip');
        $(element).tooltip('destroy');
        }
    }
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.temp1 = ko.observable(25);

    self.temp2 = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.temp1();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                self.temp1(value);
            }
        },
        owner: this
    }).extend({ rateLimit: 500 });

    self.temp3 = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.temp1() * 3;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                value = value / 3;
                self.temp1(value.toFixed(2));
            }
        },
        owner: this
    }).extend({ rateLimit: 500 });
    self.init = function(){
        ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById('model'));
        delete self.init;
      };

    self.temp4 = ko.observable('sds');
};
var model = new ViewModel();
$().ready(model.init());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the writer

```
if (!isNaN(value)) {
    self.temp1(value);
}
```

prevents an invalid `value` ever be stored in `temp2`.

You could store that invalid `value` in an inner cache like this:

```
self.temp2 = (function() {
    var invalidVal = ko.observable();

    return ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (invalidVal()) return invalidVal();
            else return self.temp1();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                self.temp1(value);
                invalidVal(undefined);
            } else {
                invalidVal(value);
            }
        },
        owner: this
    });
}()).extend({ rateLimit: 500 });
```

Updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/88vnx9ka/9/

BTW

- fixed syntax problem, it's not `validate {pattern...`, it's `validate: {pattern...`.
- don't know why you need to restore to last valid value after 3 secs. The behaviour confused me for minutes. So I disabled the feature to demonstrate this solution.

**Update**

Fixed temp3 format with `toFixed(2)` in reader.

Comment: I restore old value because this validation is used on invoice and when price are invalid, total and subtotal are wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works on my real script. You made my day.